Spark Shell: spark.executor.extraJavaOptions is not allowed to set Spark options
I created this Spark Shell programm, but i got this error while running it:
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3> spark-submit --properties-file C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\conf\spark-defaults.conf 'C:\Users\JainRonit\OneDrive - STCO\Desktop\Personal\Study\Coding\Pyspark\02-Spark-First-Project\HelloSpark.py'
24/07/26 11:13:49 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.5.1
24/07/26 11:13:49 INFO SparkContext: OS info Windows 11, 10.0, amd64
24/07/26 11:13:49 INFO SparkContext: Java version 11.0.23
24/07/26 11:13:50 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
24/07/26 11:13:50 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.Exception: spark.executor.extraJavaOptions is not allowed to set Spark options (was '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=app-logs -Dlogfile.name=HelloSpark'). Set them directly on a SparkConf or in a properties file when using ./bin/spark-submit.
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.$anonfun$validateSettings$4(SparkConf.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.$anonfun$validateSettings$4$adapted(SparkConf.scala:521)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:521)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
24/07/26 11:13:50 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
24/07/26 11:13:50 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JainRonit\OneDrive - STCO\Desktop\Personal\Study\Coding\Pyspark\02-Spark-First-Project\HelloSpark.py", line 13, in <module>
    .getOrCreate()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 497, in getOrCreate
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 515, in getOrCreate
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 203, in __init__
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 296, in _do_init
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 421, in _initialize_context
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1587, in __call__
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.Exception: spark.executor.extraJavaOptions is not allowed to set Spark options (was '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=app-logs -Dlogfile.name=HelloSpark'). Set them directly on a SparkConf or in a properties file when using ./bin/spark-submit.
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.$anonfun$validateSettings$4(SparkConf.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.$anonfun$validateSettings$4$adapted(SparkConf.scala:521)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:521)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

24/07/26 11:13:50 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/07/26 11:13:50 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\JainRonit\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-0326d309-090a-4a5f-af13-d7fe347ab38d

This is the code that produces the error:
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark import SparkConf
from lib.logger import Log4j

# conf = SparkConf()
# conf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=app-logs -Dlogfile.name=hello-spark")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("Hello Spark") \
            .master("local[3") \
            .getOrCreate()

    logger = Log4j(spark)
    logger.info("Starting HelloSpark")

    # your processing code

    logger.info("Finished HelloSpark")

    # spark.stop()

My spark-default.conf file:
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=app-logs -Dlogfile.name=HelloSpark

Python Version: 3.12.4
Java Version: 11.0.23
I attempted to execute my code after configuring the default settings in the spark-defaults.conf file, but I encountered the above error when executing it.

I resolved this issue using spark in the conda environment, with JAVA version 17 and Python Version as 3.8


(pyspark) PS C:\Users\JainRonit\OneDrive - STCO\Desktop\Personal\Study\Coding\Pyspark\Spark-Project> python --version
Python 3.8.19
(pyspark) PS C:\Users\JainRonit\OneDrive - STCO\Desktop\Personal\Study\Coding\Pyspark\Spark-Project> JAva -version
java version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207, mixed mode, sharing)
(pyspark) PS C:\Users\JainRonit\OneDrive - STCO\Desktop\Personal\Study\Coding\Pyspark\Spark-Project> pyspark --version
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '2a139a55' at 'null' in 'null'
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for 'Default' at 'null' in 'null'
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.5.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.18, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.11
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ubuntu on 2024-08-06T11:36:15Z
Revision bb7846dd487f259994fdc69e18e03382e3f64f42
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
Type --help for more information.
(pyspark) PS C:\Users\JainRonit\OneDrive - STCO\Desktop\Personal\Study\Coding\Pyspark\Spark-Project> spark-shell --version
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '2a139a55' at 'null' in 'null'
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for 'Default' at 'null' in 'null'
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.5.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.18, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.11
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ubuntu on 2024-08-06T11:36:15Z
Revision bb7846dd487f259994fdc69e18e03382e3f64f42
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
Type --help for more information.
(pyspark) PS C:\Users\JainRonit\OneDrive - STCO\Desktop\Personal\Study\Coding\Pyspark\Spark-Project>




Posting a few version numbers doesn't answer the question. This answer contains no other information.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

try this:
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -Dlogfile.name=HelloSpark
spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=app-logs 


Still receiving the same error.
